# Vim match weird behaviour

Tags: vim

I¡ve setup the following match to highlight `TODO`s in my code:

```
hi todo guifg=#b294bb
match todo /TODO:?/
```

But the rule doesn't match the optionsl colon in `TODO:` (CoffeeScript file):

[image]

I've tried some Regex variations, like escaping the colon or wrapping it with parens.

The weird thing is that it works differently in some filetypes, for example:

- In my screenshot (CoffeeScript) it doesn't matches the colon.
- In LESS, it doesn't match anything.
- In vim file, it matches both TODO and the colon.

What am I missing? Is something in my language syntax files overriding this rule?

Notice that I'm using AfterColors plugin to create this colours customisations.

Comment: Where is this definition in your config? `:match` applies to the current window only, not every file when loaded. Did you want `:syntax match`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "todo" group already exists (and matches `/TODO/`), try using another name.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark matches a literal question mark in vim regex (by default). If you set the mode to very magic with `\v` you will get the behavior you are expecting. (Or use `\?`)

```
match todo /\v\CTODO:?/
```

It is recommended to set the magic mode and case sensitivity explicitly when using regex in scripts since they are affected by user settings.

Read `:h magic` and `:h \C`

Comment: Is still doesn't match the colon in CoffeeScript and doesn't matches anything in LESS. Very confused about this.

Comment: @jviotti you might be conflicting with some of the default syntax highlighting rules or setting these too early.